# What is a convincing way to replace missing values in income data in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I am working with NLS data. It's cross-sectional data for different variables in 2013. On of my independent variables is annual income. I start off with 7k respondents and if I would drop data for the negative income and NA's I will reduce my sample to 5k. So I am thinking about replacing the NA's with the average and negatives with a 0.

Do you think that replacing is better then dropping, considering the size of my sample? For the replacing option, how would I code it? My dataset name is nlsy.

Comment: Your proposal does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: Specifically, I want to run a logistic regression of marital status on age, age^2, religion importance, gender, race, education level, income, hours worked and residence area. It is a pretty simple model and the assignment is more about utilizing R than the research topic. Although, I will have to emphasize the weaknesses of my specification. With the variables income and hours worked I have the issues of negative values as well as NA's, this why I am thinking to replace the values instead of dropping them.

Comment: @Roland: Would you have any constructive feedback?

Comment: Yes, consult a statistician.

Comment: I would suggest as Sotos, there are various approach to imputation (see [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#imputation) package for example). You need to search some more to find the one that suits your objective.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm new to this forum and really appreciate it.

Comment: You could have separate variables for positive and negative income which could either be the income or indicator variables or a mix.  Regarding missings, there are quite a few imputation packages in R. See https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

Answer (score 2):

Dropping your observations with NA's and negative values would not be a good idea, since there is probably a systematic related to the missingness. If you don't take care about that your estimates will be biased. You can search in google for `missing mechanisms` or `MCAR`, `MAR` & `NMAR` for more details.

Your missing values could be replaced with (multiple) imputation methods. A popular `R` package is `mice`. Here is an example, how the package could be used:

```
library("mice")

# Example data
N <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(income = runif(N, 1000, 10000) + rnorm(N, 0, 200),
              x1 = rnorm(N),
              x2 = rnorm(N))
dat$income[sample(1:N, 100)] <- NA

# Imputation
imp <- mice(dat, m = 1) # m = 1 creates a single imputation; a higher m would result in a multiple imputation
dat_imp <- complete(imp)
```

Regarding your negative values you should investigate why they are negative and act accordingly. There is probably a specific systematic reason for their appearance, if you have many of them.

Comment: Thank you, I remember going over this topic in class, and I can see that there probably is a pattern for people where there is an NA. I decided to replace the NA's with the Median and I know there are probably more sophisticated remedies.

Comment: In the end, this is of course your decision. However, you should keep in mind that replacing NA's with the median is known to result in strongly biased estimates.

Comment: That sounds really bad, almost like my analysis is worthless. Is there a stronger case to replace NA's with the mean?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I strongly recommend to look into imputation. Like you can see in my code above, its only 2 lines of code and your estimates should improve a lot.

Comment: I will try it out. About the package, I get the following error: > library(mice)
Error in library(mice) : there is no package called ‘mice’
> library("mice")
Error in library("mice") : there is no package called ‘mice’ Is that an outdated package?

Comment: If you are using a package in R the first time, you need to install it first (that has to be done for new packages in general). This can be done with the command `install.packages("mice")`.